# Check first element of the array needs to be unique

Tags: java, arrays, unique

I have a semicolon separated text file. The idea is to read the text file line by line. Every line will be splitted to an array element.

Now I want to do some checks like is the ID (first element called "Referenz") unique, are all mandatory "fields" filled, etc...

I guess I have to take the ID and put it to an list. And for the next line I have to compare the ID with the IDs from the list?

So question is that the right way and what / how to realise that.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Test_Line2Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String strLine = "Referenz;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7;Titel;Name1;Name2;Name3;field8;field9;field10;field11;field12;field13;field14;Street;field15;ZIP;field16;city;field17;dob;field18;field19;field20;field21;field22;field23;field24;field25;field26;field27;field28;field29;field30;field31;field32;field33;field34;field35;field36;field37;field38;field39;phone;mobile;CustomField1;CustomField2;CustomField3;CustomField4;CustomField5;CustomField6;CustomField7;CustomField8;CustomField9;CustomField10";


//declaration 
String[] stringArray;
String delimiter = ";";

// allocates memory for 59 strings
stringArray = new String[59];

// split the String after separator ";"
stringArray = strLine.split(";", -1);



// print array
for(int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(j + " " + stringArray[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If all you want to do is check if they're unique, but you don't care which one is a duplicate in the case of one, just add all the first elements into a set, then check if the set is the same size as the array. If the set is smaller, there's duplicates.

Comment: No need to allocate the elements of the array, as `String.split()` allocates and returns a _new_ array itself. Just declare the array and initialize it in one go: `String[] stringArray = strLine.split(";", -1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to split the string with delimiter `;` and add separated Strings to a `List`, where you can easily validate with the `Collections.frequency()` static method returning the number as `int` of the occurence.

```
String[] values = strLine.split(";");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(values);

if (Collections.frequency(list, list.get(0) > 1) {
    System.out.println("The first value is not unique in the list");
}
```

---

Since Java 8 feel free to use **Stream**:

```
if (list.stream().filter(a -> a.equals(list.get(0))).count() > 1) {
    System.out.println("The first value is not unique in the list");
}
```

Comment: I can not see any downvotings - just upvoting (useful) clicks

Comment: +2/-1, you have no privilege yet to see the ratio.. it doesn't matter, I am only curious how can I improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// allocates memory for 59 strings
stringArray = new String[59];

// split the String after separator ";"
stringArray = strLine.split(";", -1);
```

Initializing the String[59] isn't helping you; the split method is just returning something that overwrites it immediately afterwards.

If you needed to check for any duplicates, using a HashSet would help here.

If you only need to make sure the *first* element isn't duplicated, you can just do it in a loop.  You've already got one, so...

```
// print array
for(int j = 0; j < stringArray.length; j++) {
        if (stringArray[0].equals(stringArray(j)) { 
            System.out.println("Duplicate!");
        }
        System.out.println(j + " " + stringArray[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Allocating array fixed for 59 items may not be a good way. That's I prefer to use List over arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the first element is unique, you can use the following:

```
Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(stringArray), stringArray[0]) == 1
```

This returns a `boolean` that is `true` if the first element of `stringArray` is unique, otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 0):

For each line, put its `Referenz` in a `HashSet`. Then checking if a subsequent `Referenz` is unique would be as simple as `referenzSet.contains(theNewReferenz)`